# Jest: Test the function which call another function that returns promise

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs, ts-jest

I am testing a function which calls another function that return promise, I have tried with async/await, done and resolves and rejects but nothing work. code -

```
let total = 0;

function sum(a, b) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(a + b);
        }, 0)
    });
}

function wrapper() {
    sum(2,3)
        .then(data => {
            total = data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

describe('Test', () => {
    it('adds 2 + 3 to equal 5', () => {
        // want to call wrapper and test that total is equal to 5 
    });
})
```

I want to call the wrapper function and wait till, then or catch block executes and it stores the data to total, but jest is not waiting for it.

Comment: In documentation they have provided only that scenario when function returns promise but in my case function is not directly returning promise but it calls another function and that returns promise

Comment: The only way for you to accomplish this is here: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks. You have to use the "done" callback so that Jest can tell your test is complete.